# Onchange refresh when adding a new item

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, html-datalist

onchange works fine when selecting items from a datalist. The problem arises when I want to modify some element. Then they add another onchange and the modified text disappears once it is refreshed.

What should he do to save the modification when adding another onchange?

```js
function information(ele){
  var address1 = document.getElementsByClassName('test2');
  for(var i=0; i<address1.length; i++){
    if( ele.value == "test4"){
      address1[i].value = "test5";
    } else if (ele.value == "test6"){
      address1[i].value = "test7";
    } else if (ele.value == "test8"){
      address1[i].value = "test9";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form grup information">
  <lable for="dates-full.names"> Names full</lable>
  <input name="dates-full.names" list="dates-full.names" type="text"
    class="form grup test1" onchange="information(this)">
  <datalist type="text" id="dates-full.names">
    <option value="test4">
    <option value="test6">
    <option value="test8">
  </datalist>
</div>


<div class="form grup test2">
  <lable for="power-full.adress"> Adress full</lable>
  <input id="test2" name="dates-full.adress" list="dates-full.adress" type="text"
  class="form grup test2">
  <datalist type="text" id="dates-full.adress">
    <option value="test5">
    <option value="test7">
    <option value="test9">
  </datalist>
</div>
```